# form validation in php/ajax

Tags: php, ajax

i was trying to add an exception like if user input nothing or input wrong 'Contact ID' and press enter, an error message will come out & notifying user that ID not found. any help? thanks in advance:) here is my index.html file.

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function ajaxFunction(e){
    var e=e || window.event;
    var keycode=e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(keycode==13 || (e.target||e.srcElement).value==''){ 
    var http;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible! 

    try{ 
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari 
        http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } catch (e){ 
        // Internet Explorer Browsers 
        try{ 
            http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        } catch (e) { 
            try{ 
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
            } catch (e){ 
                // Something went wrong 
                alert("Your browser broke!"); 
                return false; 
            } 
        }
    }

    var url = "getagentids.php?param=";
                var idValue = document.getElementById("agid").value;
                var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);  // cache buster
                http.open("GET", "getagentids.php?param=" + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
                http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
                http.send(null);
         function handleHttpResponse() {
                    if (http.readyState == 4) {
                        results = http.responseText.split(",");
                        document.getElementById('agfn').value = results[0];
                        document.getElementById('agsal').value = results[1];
                        document.getElementById('agtel').value = results[2];
                        document.getElementById('agid').value = results[3];
                    }
                } 
    }
}

</script> 

       <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact ID:</td>
                    <td><input id="agid" type="text"
                               name="contactid" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(event)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tel Number:</td>
                    <td><input id="agtel" type="text"
                               name="contacttel"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="agfn" type="text"
                               name="contactfullname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salutation:</td>
                    <td><input id="agsal" type="text"
                               name="contactsalutation"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Clear"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: so what is your problem , is your code not working ??

Comment: @Kanishka

tq for reply. i've tried to add exception using JS but it didn't work for me. that pop-up came out although the 'contact id' is in database. so i remove that code from index. any idea to validate the id?

Comment: I believe, `e.target||e.srcElement` will give you a TRUE/FALSE value. But you are trying to access the value property of it in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do the basic validation using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact').keypress(function(e){ //when user presses a key in that Input Box
      var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
      if(code == 13) // check if it is Enter Key
      {
        if($(this).val().trim().length == 0) // check if it is empty
            alert("Error: Shouldn't be empty !");
        else
        {
            // You are good to go here
        }
      }
    });
});​
```

HTML:

```
<input id="contact" name="contact" value="" />​
```

If you wish to test it live, goto: http://jsfiddle.net/NFSTL/

I binded the [KeyPress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event to that InputBox.

Hope it helps. :)

---

**EDIT**

Without using jQuery:

```
function ajaxFunction(e){
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;

    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;

    if(code==13)
    {
        if(targ.value.trim().length == 0)
            alert("Error: This shouldn't be empty!");
        else
        {
            //do the sending and receiving of data here...
        }
    }
}​
```

HTML:

```
<input id="agid" type="text" name="contactid" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(event)" />​
```

For live testing: http://jsfiddle.net/SYf4C/

Here's an excellent tutorial I used: [quirksmode.org/js/events_properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

I would say that, jQuery makes life easier. :)
Because it is a JavaScript library composed to work in almost all browsers.

Comment: thanks @Akhilesh for your answer:) but is there any other way rather than using jQuery?

Comment: Excellent!! thanks a lot @Akhilesh :) but how to show error msg if user input wrong id? [i,e. ID not found in database]

Comment: If you were using jQuery, you could have used the callback function `success`, which would have returned the `data`. Check this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i'm even newbie in ajax & don't have any idea about jQuery :(

Comment: It would be worth learning it. :) Give it a try. Wish you all the best.

Answer (score 1):

Main page Coding:

```
 $('.vote').click(function() {
        var valueid=$(this).attr("alt");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "voteajax.php",
            data: "votebtn="+valueid+""
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            var received_data=msg.trim();
            if(received_data=='0')
            {
                alert('Please sign in to vote!');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('received data'+received_data);
                gg2=received_data.split("/");
                var x=gg2[0];
                var no_of_vote=gg2[1];
                $('#totalnoofvotespan').html(no_of_vote);
                window.location='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>';
            }
        });


//Ajax Page Coding


    $poll_choice = $_POST['votebtn'];
    $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $date=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $ex=explode(",",$poll_choice);
    $pollid=$ex[0];
    $choiceid=$ex[1];
    if($userid=="")
    {   
        echo "0";   
    }
    else
    {
        ..// Your coding 
        echo $choiceid."/".$numofvote;   // Echo the identifier and access this identifier in main page for message notification
    }
```

The first one is the main page coding
In the above coding i passed argument to ajax page. In ajax page it gets the values from the main page and if it is not valid it echo the identify code. Using that code we can say "It is not a valid one". Like this u have to try. I think this may helps you

Comment: I think, if you had done some indenting on the code, it would be easy for the viewers to read.

Comment: @sindhu
i didn't get what you've done here..it seems complex to me :(